# Type hint as logical-and of multiple types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that `Union` allows you to specify the logical-or of multiple types. I'm wondering if there is a way to do something analogous for the logical-and, something like:

```
def foo(x: And[Bar, Baz]):
```

I know that one option is to just explicitly define a new type that inherits from both `Bar` and `Baz`, like this:

```
class BarAndBaz(Bar, Baz):
    ...

def foo(x: BarAndBaz):
```

In my context that option is not ideal.

Comment: Do you mean Tuple?

Comment: @JoshLee No. I edited my post to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: `Union` already means that the object may/will have methods of either/all types. For all intents and purposes it *is* an "and". Are you aware of that, or do you have a more specific reason for needing to express an *"inherits from X __and__ Y"*?

Comment: @deceze If I write `def foo(x: Union[str, dict])`, and then type `x.`, my IDE does not tab-complete to methods of `str`.

Comment: @dshin Mine does…

Comment: @deceze Aha, looks like I needed to update my PyCharm from 3.1 to 3.3. Now it works!

Comment: @deceze Though, I'm left a bit unsatisfied. Using `Union` helps with making the IDE do what I want, but it doesn't properly communicate to the reader of my code that the argument will inherit from BOTH Bar and Baz. If I could bind `And = Union`, that'd be nice, but the IDE doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: Then the IDE is at fault here. `And = Union` is a type alias and, as such, `And` should be treated as `Union` is. Specifically, the IDE's typechecker is at fault here and you should probably be submitting an issue on their tracker.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Actually, looks like `And = Union` works for my IDE, seems it just needed a restart for whatever reason. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Either post a self-answer, ping deceze to write one up if he so desires or, worse case, delete (not ideal since it might be of use to other people)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Done.

Comment: Is there any new way to address this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on helpful comments from @deceze and @JimFasarakisHilliard:

For all intents and purposes, you can use `Union` as if it were `And`, since a good IDE should auto-complete for types `Bar` and `Baz` if you declare a variable to be of type `Union[Bar, Baz]`.

Something like this will also help with readability:

```
# IDE should treat And/Union equivalently; use And[T, U] to communicate
# that a variable is expected to be an instance of T *and* U, and
# Union[T, U] to communicate that it is expected to be an instance of T
# *or* U.
And = Union
```

In my particular case, my IDE (PyCharm) was not behaving properly because it needed an update and a restart.

Comment: This might work on IDE but `mypy` will throw errors because of the `or` relation. If you are using for example a method that is only available in one of your superclasses/supertypes, you will get errors in mypy.